# fullcalendar per view options

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a little problem with fullcalendar plugin.
I want to set different options per multiple views.
For example, I want to set slotDuration and defaultTimedEventDuration for 30 min in day view, but in week view it should be 2 hours.

How can I accomplish that? Is that even possible using fullcalendar plugin? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [View-Specific Options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/) like in the example on the fullcalendar website.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    views: {
        basic: {
            // options apply to basicWeek and basicDay views
        },
        agenda: {
            // options apply to agendaWeek and agendaDay views
        },
        week: {
            // options apply to basicWeek and agendaWeek views
        },
        day: {
            // options apply to basicDay and agendaDay views
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ryan89 thanks for your help. slotDuration is now working, defaultTimedEventDuration seems can't be defined per views basis.

```
 views: {
      week: {
        defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:15:00',
        slotDuration: "00:30:00"
      },
      day: {
        defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:15:00',
        slotDuration: "00:15:00"
      },
      agendaDetailed: {
        type: 'agenda',
        buttonText: 'Detailed',
        defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:05:00',
        slotDuration: "00:05:00"
      }
    },
```